# How can I get last title from RSS?

Tags: rss, lua

I'm using lua-feeds ( http://code.matthewwild.co.uk/lua-feeds/ )

```
require "lua-feeds/feeds"

local feed = feeds.open("http://php.net/feed.atom");
for _, entry in ipairs(feed) do
bot.rooms["php@conference.aqq.eu"]:send_message(entry:get_child("title"):get_text().."\n"..entry:get_child("link").attr.href);
end
```

This is my code, that is getting full RSS. I only want to get the last title and link, how can I do that?

Comment: If `feed` is a table, then the last entry is at `feed[#feed]`.

Comment: @lhf It depends on your definition of "last". Chronologically the last (i.e. most recent) entry in the feed is `feed[1]`.

Comment: @catwell, of course, right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call *the result of* `ipairs(feed)` once.

Comment: @10minutemail: uh, `local result = ipairs(feed)`?

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand, how did that answer get accepted? `ipairs(feed)` returns an iterator over the feed, this is not what you want. You probably simply want `feed[1]`...

Comment: (I was asked on Twitter so I added a real answer.)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I don't usually handle iterators directly, so I never considered it in detail.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand how @DeadMG's answer was accepted. It looks terribly wrong to me.

`ipairs` takes a sequence and returns an iterator over it, so `ipairs(feed)` is an iterator over the feed. `ipairs` *is* called once in the example provided by the OP. *The resulting iterator* is called several times.

@DeadMG's idea was probably to call the iterator only once. This is how it would look:

```
local f, v, i = ipairs(feed)
local _, entry = f(v, i)
```

of, if you like tricks:

```
local _, _, entry = pcall(ipairs(feed))
```

But... Why would you do that? You have the feed as a table. You want the first entry of that table:

```
local entry = feed[1]
```

Done.

Comment: By the way, I don't get notified if you @ me in an answer. Also, not that I downvoted you or anything, but answers aren't typically supposed to spend their time pissing on other answers or explaining why they are wrong.